# Loop to save residuals from OLS regression

Tags: python, regression

I am running the following univariate regression:

```py
var_list = ['x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'x4']

# Run univariate regression for each x variable
y_var = 'inh'
for x_var in var_list:
    formula = y_var + ' ~ ' + x_var
    results = smf.ols(formula, data=predictors).fit(
        cov_type='HAC', cov_kwds={'maxlags': 1}
    )
```

I want to save the regression residuals for each `x_var` in a `DataFrame()`.

I know that the regression residuals can be accessed using `results.resid`, but I am lost on how to save and append the residuals for each `x` variable to a `DataFrame()`.

Udpate:

`predictors` is a `DataFrame()` that contains my `y` and `x` variables, in the following format:

```py
predictors = pd.DataFrame(
    [['31/01/2020',  -0.13, -4.01, -4.01, -3.20, -0.81],
     ['29/02/2020',  -8.67, -3.91, -4.00, -3.17, -0.74],
     ['31/03/2020', -13.13, -3.77, -3.90, -3.10, -0.67],
     ['30/04/2020',  12.00, -3.89, -3.77, -3.27, -0.62],
     ['31/05/2020',   4.67, -3.93, -3.89, -3.37, -0.56],
     ['30/06/2020',   2.00, -3.95, -3.93, -3.44, -0.51],
     ['31/07/2020',   5.52, -4.01, -3.95, -3.50, -0.51],
     ['31/08/2020',   6.95, -4.08, -4.01, -3.57, -0.51],
     ['30/09/2020',  -3.90, -4.05, -4.09, -3.53, -0.51],
     ['31/10/2020',  -2.69, -4.02, -4.05, -3.52, -0.50],
     ['30/11/2020',  10.37, -4.13, -4.02, -3.64, -0.49],
     ['31/12/2020',   4.06, -4.17, -4.13, -3.69, -0.48]],
    columns=['Date', 'y', 'x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'x4']
)
```

I need to run univariate regressions and store the residuals in the same format as above, i.e.

```
Date         resid_x1   resid_x2   resid_x3   resid_x4
31/01/2020    XX           XX         XX         XX
29/02/2020    XX           XX         XX         XX
31/03/2020    XX           XX         XX         XX
30/04/2020    XX           XX         XX         XX
31/05/2020    XX           XX         XX         XX
30/06/2020    XX           XX         XX         XX
31/07/2020    XX           XX         XX         XX
31/08/2020    XX           XX         XX         XX
30/09/2020    XX           XX         XX         XX
31/10/2020    XX           XX         XX         XX
30/11/2020    XX           XX         XX         XX
31/12/2020    XX           XX         XX         XX
```

Updated @ 17:41

I am sharing an updated version of my code.

To recap, predictors is a pandas dataframe that contains my dependent and independent variables.

```
x_var = ['x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'x4']

# Run bi-variate regression for each predictor variable
y_var = 'log_equity_premium'
for x_var in var_list_all:
    formula = y_var + ' ~ ' + x_var
    results = smf.ols(formula, data=predictors).fit(cov_type='HAC', cov_kwds={'maxlags': 1})
```

I wanted to collect the regression residuals in a Dataframe, and this what I did:

```
residuals.append(results.resid)
```

The format I wanted the DataFrame to be in is as follows:

```
Date        res_x1  res_x2  res_x3  res_x4
29-02-1996    XX      XX      XX      XX
31-03-1996    XX      XX      XX      XX    
30-04-1996    XX      XX      XX      XX    
31-05-1996    XX      XX      XX      XX    
30-06-1996    XX      XX      XX      XX
```

Basically the DataFrame should have index=date and columns = res_`dependent_var_name'

Once I had the DataFrame, I renamed the index and transposed df to get to the desired outcome, as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(residuals).rename(index={0: "res_x1", 1: "res_x2", 2: "res_x3", 3: "res_x4"}).transpose()
```

And this is how df looks like:

```
Date        res_x1  res_x2  res_x3  res_x4
29-02-1996  -0.5715 -0.7082 -0.1428 -0.0049
31-03-1996  -0.5834 -0.6383 -0.1495 -0.0166
30-04-1996  -0.0342 -0.0921  0.4025  0.5297
31-05-1996   0.9164  0.8432  1.3278  1.4535
30-06-1996  -1.0707 -1.1688 -0.707  -0.5879
```

Is there a more efficient way of getting to the above outcome?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete solution, based on your `predictors` `DataFrame()`:

```py
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf

# These settings are just to print a complete view of the data frame
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 500)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500)
pd.set_option('display.width', 1000)

predictors = pd.DataFrame(
    [['31/01/2020',  -0.13, -4.01, -4.01, -3.20, -0.81],
     ['29/02/2020',  -8.67, -3.91, -4.00, -3.17, -0.74],
     ['31/03/2020', -13.13, -3.77, -3.90, -3.10, -0.67],
     ['30/04/2020',  12.00, -3.89, -3.77, -3.27, -0.62],
     ['31/05/2020',   4.67, -3.93, -3.89, -3.37, -0.56],
     ['30/06/2020',   2.00, -3.95, -3.93, -3.44, -0.51],
     ['31/07/2020',   5.52, -4.01, -3.95, -3.50, -0.51],
     ['31/08/2020',   6.95, -4.08, -4.01, -3.57, -0.51],
     ['30/09/2020',  -3.90, -4.05, -4.09, -3.53, -0.51],
     ['31/10/2020',  -2.69, -4.02, -4.05, -3.52, -0.50],
     ['30/11/2020',  10.37, -4.13, -4.02, -3.64, -0.49],
     ['31/12/2020',   4.06, -4.17, -4.13, -3.69, -0.48]],
    columns=['Date', 'y', 'x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'x4']
)

# x1, x2, x3, x4
for _ in range(1, 5):
    formula = f'y ~ x{_}'
    results = smf.ols(formula, data=predictors).fit(
        cov_type='HAC', cov_kwds={'maxlags': 1}
    )
 
    # Maybe there is a more efficient way than this
    predictors.insert(len(predictors.columns), formula, results.resid)

print(predictors)
```

The code above will give you the following output:

```
          Date      y    x1    x2    x3    x4     y ~ x1     y ~ x2     y ~ x3     y ~ x4
0   31/01/2020  -0.13 -4.01 -4.01 -3.20 -0.81  -2.113471  -1.051958   2.997339   5.527911
1   29/02/2020  -8.67 -3.91 -4.00 -3.17 -0.74  -7.277645  -9.753755  -4.912915  -5.128155
2   31/03/2020 -13.13 -3.77 -3.90 -3.10 -0.67  -7.011490 -15.831729  -7.903505 -11.704221
3   30/04/2020  12.00 -3.89 -3.77 -3.27 -0.62  14.067520   7.194905  13.657929  11.914303
4   31/05/2020   4.67 -3.93 -3.89 -3.37 -0.56   5.387190   1.806473   4.228773   2.770533
5   30/06/2020   2.00 -3.95 -3.93 -3.44 -0.51   2.042024  -0.216337   0.089364  -1.410943
6   31/07/2020   5.52 -4.01 -3.95 -3.50 -0.51   3.536529   3.627258   2.349870   2.109057
7   31/08/2020   6.95 -4.08 -4.01 -3.57 -0.51   2.603451   6.028042   2.310460   3.539057
8   30/09/2020  -3.90 -4.05 -4.09 -3.53 -0.51  -7.233801  -3.527579  -7.699877  -7.310943
9   31/10/2020  -2.69 -4.02 -4.05 -3.52 -0.50  -5.011053  -2.964769  -6.279961  -6.403238
10  30/11/2020  10.37 -4.13 -4.02 -3.64 -0.49   4.335538   9.609839   4.261051   6.354467
11  31/12/2020   4.06 -4.17 -4.13 -3.69 -0.48  -3.324792   5.079611  -3.098527  -0.257828
```

Please, let me know if that helps.

Comment: [Note](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html): *Iteratively appending rows to a DataFrame can be more computationally intensive than a single concatenate. A better solution is to append those rows to a list and then concatenate the list with the original DataFrame all at once.*

Comment: @Neither, thanks for the tip. I added another example, following your advice. Is that what you meant to?

Comment: Hi guys. Thanks for helping out. The code works...But I was wondering is there a way to have the dataframe with the x variables as columns and the residuals as the rows?

Comment: @Parvesh, can you update the question and post an example of the desired output?

Comment: I've updated my original post, showing what predictors mean and the desired output. Please do let me know if you need more details. And many thanks for your help.

Comment: @accdias Yes it was. I hope the answer is clear and understandable enough for the question asker.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation, @Neither. Parvesh, I will take a look at the update and I will see if I can come up with a solution.